# Setting tab delimiter on just one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this when read in as a pandas dataframe:

```
          OBJECTID_1           AP_CODE
0         857720               137\t62\t005\tNE
1         857721               137\t62\t004\tNW
2         857724               137\t62\t004\tNE
3         857726               137\t62\t003\tNE
4         857728               137\t62\t003\tNW
5         857729               137\t62\t002\tNW
```

df.info() returns this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9313 entries, 0 to 9312
Data columns (total 2 columns):
OBJECTID_1    9312 non-null float64
AP_CODE       9313 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 181.9+ KB
None
```

and `print(repr(open(r'P:\file.csv').read(100)))`

returns this:

```
'OBJECTID_1,AP_CODE\n857720,"137\t62\t005\tNE"\n857721,"137\t62\t004\tNW"\n857724,"137\t62\t004\tNE"\n857726,"137\t'
```

I want to get rid of the `\t` in the column `AP_CODE` but I can't figure out why it is even there, or how to remove it.  `.replace` doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `df['AP_CODE'].str.replace('\t', ' ')`? this works for me, also the tabs are in your data, it's not something that magically gets inserted

Comment: that seemed to work, I didn't add `.str` when I did it before, thank you.

Comment: `.replace` looks for exact matches in your data, whilst `.str.replace` looks for the presence of the strings in your data to replace is the semantic difference

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use tabs in replacement, you need to use a raw string by prefexing your string literal with `r`:

```
In [299]: df.AP_CODE.str.replace(r'\\t',' ')
Out[299]:
0    137 62 005 NE
1    137 62 004 NW
2    137 62 004 NE
3    137 62 003 NE
4    137 62 003 NW
5    137 62 002 NW
Name: AP_CODE, dtype: object
```

Comment: `r` prefix is unnecessary here as you're already escaping the tab

Comment: actually it doesn't work if i leave out the r prefix (try it) ... i don't really understand why though

Comment: well this worked fine for me `df['AP_CODE'].str.replace('\t', ' ')` so I'm not sure it'll depend on how you loaded the data perhaps but the OP said my code worked for them

Comment: i loaded the data with `read_clipboard` ... is it a python 2/3 difference maybe?